# How do I deploy my Azure Service Fabric application to the local cluster consistently and successfully?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am deploying and redeploying Azure Service Fabric applications in a local cluster. While initial deployment to the cluster went smoothly, redeployment results in about a 50% success rate with various intermittent errors.

Errors in the output window of Visual Studio:

- `Unable to determine whether the application is installed on the cluster or not.`
- `Something is taking too long, the application is still not ready.`

Errors in Service Fabric Explorer (SFX):

- One application instance OK, the other shows an error

  [image: One application instance OK, the other shows an error]
- Error in `fabric:/System/DnsService`: `DnsService UDP Listener is unable to start`

  [image: Error in fabric System DnsService]
- Error in `fabric:/System/EventStoreService`: `System.Net.HttpListenerException`

  [image: Error in fabric System Event Store Service]

**How do I deploy my application to the local cluster consistently and successfully?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio's Properties window, **change the Application Debug Mode from Refresh to Remove Application**.

[image: Application Debug Mode Remove Application]

**I deployed my app 10 times in a row with no errors!**

Caveat: The one disadvantage to this solution is that if you remove your local cluster and then redeploy, Service Fabric Explorer (SFX) will throw several errors for a few minutes such as `Get cluster upgrade progress failed`

[image: Get cluster upgrade progress failed]