# No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm new to Azure and Service Fabric.
Today I installed the VS Service Fabric tools and the SDK (latest 3.3.617)
My home desktop has Win10 pro x64 with 8GB RAM.

I tried to run a "hello world" app from the "new project" using VS. Compilation works and then it starts to spin up the local cluster.

I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Stateless1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Stateless1 -> C:\Users\USER\source\repos\Application2\Stateless1\bin\x64\Debug\Stateless1.exe
2>------ Build started: Project: Application2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Deploy started: Project: Application2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Started executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
3>Finished executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
3>Time elapsed: 00:00:00.4751003
3>Started executing script 'Set-LocalClusterReady'.
3>powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\DefaultLocalClusterSetup.psm1'; Set-LocalClusterReady -createOneNodeCluster $true"
3>--------------------------------------------
3>Local Service Fabric Cluster is not setup...
3>Please wait while we setup the Local Service Fabric Cluster. This may take few minutes...
3>Performing Stop-Service on service: FabricHostSvc . This may take a few minutes...
3>
3>Using Cluster Data Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Data
3>Using Cluster Log Root: C:\SfDevCluster\Log
3>
3>The generated json path is C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE26D.tmp.json
3>Processing and validating cluster config.
3>Check if machine 'ComputerFullName' is IOT Core: False. Could not open registry key.
3>Performing Stop-Service on service: FabricHostSvc . This may take a few minutes...
3>Create node configuration succeeded
3>Performing Start-Service on service: FabricHostSvc . This may take a few minutes...
3>
3>Waiting for Service Fabric Cluster to be ready. This may take a few minutes...
3>Local Cluster ready status: 4% completed.
3>Local Cluster ready status: 8% completed.
3>Local Cluster ready status: 100% completed.
3>WARNING: Service Fabric Cluster is taking longer than expected to connect.
3>
3>Waiting for fabric:/System/NamingService to be ready. This may take a few minutes...
3>Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS 
3>issue.
3>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:979 char:12
3>+     [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @connParams)
3>+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException
3>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
3> 
3>fabric:/System/NamingService ready status: 8% completed.
3>fabric:/System/NamingService ready status: 17% completed.
3>fabric:/System/NamingService ready status: 92% completed.
3>fabric:/System/NamingService ready status: 100% completed.
3>WARNING: fabric:/System/NamingService is taking longer than expected to be ready...
3>Local Service Fabric Cluster created successfully.
3>--------------------------------------------------
3>Launching Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager...
3>You can use Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager (system tray application) to manage your local dev cluster.
3>Finished executing script 'Set-LocalClusterReady'.
3>Time elapsed: 00:12:29.9792319
3>The PowerShell script failed to execute.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried closing down my Windows firewall and debugging again, now getting:
Unable to determine whether the application is installed on the cluster or not

Comment: I would recommend you RESET the cluster using the Cluster Manager (system tray icon) and then start again. If this does not bring the cluster UP, I recommend you uninstall the SDK, **Restart** the computer, Install again, **Restart** the computer, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to determine whether the application is installed on the cluster or not

I have encountered this error before and have solved it in 2 ways:

1. I simply redeployed to the local cluster.
2. I stopped the local cluster from the tray menu before redeploying.

[image: Stop Local Cluster from the tray menu]

Comment: I tried stopping the cluster and starting over, but this was not working well because of the first error (which now happens with or without firewall)

Comment: The other approach I've used to deal with ASF finickiness errors is to change [Application Debug Mode from Refresh to Remove Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53879811/5587356) in Visual Studio. But you may have to use @Diego Mendes's approach above.